# find the solutions to the equation $4\sin^2\theta + 1 = 6\sin\theta$ in the interval $0^\circ \leq \theta < 360^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

Find the solutions to the following equation for $0^\circ \leq θ < 360^\circ$:

$$4\sin^2 θ + 1 = 6\sin θ$$

My work:

$$4\sin^2\theta - 6\sin\theta + 1 = 0$$

Factor

$$\sin\theta= \frac{1}{4}(3+ \sqrt{5}) \qquad \text{and} \qquad \sin\theta = \frac{1}{4}(3- \sqrt{5})$$

$$\theta = \arcsin\left[\frac{1}{4}(3+ \sqrt{5})\right] \qquad \text{and} \qquad \theta = \arcsin\left[\frac{1}{4}(3- \sqrt{5})\right]$$

When I take the inverse sin they both come out >1 (no solution), what did I do wrong?

---

\begin{align*}
2\cos^2\theta - 2\cos\theta - 1 & = 0\\
\cos\theta & = \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{4+8}}{4} && \text{quadratic formula}\\
\cos\theta & = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{3}}{2}\\
\theta & = \arccos\left[\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2}\right]\\
\theta & = 111.5^\circ
\end{align*}

Is this correct?

Comment: slight error at the end: $\frac14 (3-√5)< 1$ so arcsin is defined on it.

Comment: @EmilianoSorbello thank you, could you please assist me with the second part? I have edited the original post :), thank you.

Comment: You can see how I typeset your equations by right-clicking on the equation, then selecting Show Math As TeX Commands.  Also, please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you mean? $\frac{3 -\sqrt 5}4 = 0.19098$  and $\theta = 11.01^\circ, 168.989^\circ.
$

Comment: Thank you!! Must have made an error when inserting it into my calculator!

Comment: Hello, could you please assist me with the second part which I added on to the original post with an edit and tell me what I did wrong, thank you/

Comment: @iforgotmyoldemail  you also need $180^circ - \cos^{-1}(1/2 - \sqrt3/2) = 248.529^\circ.$  in general, $\cos x=  a $ gives you $x = \cos^{-1}(a), 180^\circ - \cos^{-1}(a)$

Answer (score 0):

The domain of arcsin is $[-1,1]$, the co-domain is $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$

So you have only the solution $a = arcsin((3-\sqrt5)/4)$. That's because you cannot take arcsin from $(3+\sqrt5)/4$, as it's not in the domain.

Then ... given that your $sin$ value $(3-\sqrt5)/4$ is in $(0, 1)$, you conclude that $0 < a < \pi/2$. From that follows that $\pi - a$ is also a solution. And obviously you have no more solutions in $[0, 2\pi)$. So you have 2 solutions here: $a$ and $\pi-a$.